# In SpringBoot how to ensure @Async method1 execute before @Asyn method2?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, concurrency

Say i have method1 and method2, i want to make sure that method2 is to be executed after method1 is finished. The code snippets go as following, but method2 may start before method1, how can i ensure that?

```
    @Async("executor")
    public void method1(){
      // Do somthing
    }

    @Async("executor")
    public void mehthod2(){
      // Do something
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
      method1();  // how to ensure that method2 is execute after method1 is over?
      method2();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do same, I would prefer doing it with [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

**ReadWriteLock**

```
  private ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    @Async("executor")
      public void method1(){
      readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        // Do somthing
        readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
      }

      @Async("executor")
      public void mehthod2(){
       //lies dormant until the lock has been acquired
       readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        // Do something
        readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
      }

      @Override
      public void run(){
        method1();  // how to ensure that method2 is execute after method1 is over?
        method2();
      }
```